# gem paranoia - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In my application I have below models

fee.rb

```
class Fee < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :instructor_student
  belongs_to :instructor
  has_many :fee_payment_notifications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

fee_payment_notifications.rb

```
class FeePaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fee
end
```

instructor.rb

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fees
  has_many :fee_payment_notifications, through: :fees
end
```

I want to do inner join fee with fee payment notifications
when i use joins of fee directly with fee payment notifications it give me below error

```
@instructor.fee_payment_notifications.joins(:fee)

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "fees"
LINE 1: ..."."id" = "fee_payment_notifications"."fee_id" AND "fees"."de...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "fees_fee_payment_notifications".
: SELECT "fee_payment_notifications".* FROM "fee_payment_notifications" INNER JOIN "fees" "fees_fee_payment_notifications" ON "fees_fee_payment_notifications"."id" = "fee_payment_notifications"."fee_id" AND "fees"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "fees" ON "fee_payment_notifications"."fee_id" = "fees"."id" WHERE "fees"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "fees"."instructor_id" = $1
```

May be it beacause of deleted_at field, That's why i want to do manual joins with below query

```
@instructor.fee_payment_notifications.select("fee_payment_notifications.* from fee_payment_notifications AS fp INNER JOIN fees as f ON fp.fee_id = f.id")
```

It give me below error

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: ...ns AS fp INNER JOIN fees as f ON fp.fee_id = f.id FROM "fee_...
                                                             ^
    : SELECT fee_payment_notifications.* from fee_payment_notifications AS fp INNER JOIN fees as f ON fp.fee_id = f.id FROM "fee_payment_notifications" INNER JOIN "fees" ON "fee_payment_notifications"."fee_id" = "fees"."id" WHERE "fees"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "fees"."instructor_id" = $1
    => #

How should I write query for manually join of fee and fee payment notifications?

Comment: Write it like `@instructor.fee_payment_notifications.joins(:fees).select("fee_payment_notifications.*")`. What you wrote is producing invalid SQL. Rails `.select()` is not being used like that.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it should be `join(fee)` which also not working

Comment: Rails has a method calls `.joins()` not `.join()`.. What is the new error? You have `has_many :fees`, so it should be `joins(:fees)`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes,  i mean to say joins(:fee) . i want to joins fees with fee payment notifications, not for instructor check my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not query issue. It's because of [paranoia](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) gem.
So you should write this in your model.

`acts_as_paranoid without_default_scope: true`

Please check [this](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) link. you can find *adding the default scope*.